# "You must stay for dinner!" is not a command or statement of an unalterable fact. What is it?

Tags: phrases, terminology

I'm writing a short article and now I'm stumped, thought I'd turn to your collective intelligence to help out.

"You must stay for dinner!"

It's not exactly an imperative, I think, because the subtext is something like, "We would be happy if you accepted our hospitality", which implies a request but doesn't command anything. So how might I describe that in a few words? Is it a "friendly offer"? But I'm hoping for something more exact, if there's a linguistic term for this kind of phrase, for example.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An *exhortation*?

Comment: "Part of speech" refers to the function of a single word--noun, verb, adjective, determiner, relative pronoun, etc. A whole sentence isn't a part of speech. You seem to mean "What type of sentence is ...".

Comment: An enthusiastic invitation.

Comment: a heartfelt plea

Comment: With some of my relatives it was a threat.

Answer (score 2):

an **exhortation**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhortation) A *suprahortative* modality in English

1. The act or an instance of exhorting.
2. A speech or discourse that encourages, incites, or earnestly advises.

As in:

"You must stay for dinner" she [exhorted](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhort)!